# [Error]The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to Stack

Tags: java, arraylist, stack, depth-first-search

I am a beginner in Java and I need to print the DFS of a graph using it's arraylists to store the adjacency list. When I try to compile I am getting the following errors:

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from Object to Integer
The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to Stack
The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to Stack
```

The code is the following:

```
package principal;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Stack;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String []arg)
    {
        ArrayList<List<Integer>>L=new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();
        ArrayList<Integer>l=new ArrayList<Integer>();
        int nod;
        Scanner sc = null;

        try {
            sc=new Scanner(new File("Graph.txt"));
            while (sc.hasNextInt())
            {
                do
                {
                    nod=sc.nextInt();
                    if(nod!=0) l.add(nod);
                }while(nod!=0);
                L.add((List<Integer>) l.clone());
                l.clear();
            }

            Stack stack = new Stack();
            Stack viz = new Stack();
            System.out.println("Root: ");
            Integer root = sc.nextInt();
            stack.push(root);
            while (!stack.isEmpty())
                {
                    Integer node = stack.pop();
                    System.out.print(node + " ");
                    viz[node]=1;
                    for (Integer child : L.get(node))
                    {
                        if(viz[child]!=1)
                            {
                                stack.push(child);
                            }
                    }
                }

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally{sc.close();}
    }

}
```

The Graph.txt contains the following

```
2 3 4
1 3 4
1 2 4
1 2 3
```

Comment: That code is a hot mess.  Odds are you are comparing an item of arrayList L to an integer, and since arrayList L is an arraylist of lists<Integer> it can't be compared.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use array syntax (`array[index]`) for stacks, you have to use `push()`, `pop()`, and `peek()`

Stacks work on a first-in, last-out basis. So, the only element in the stack that is accessible is the top one. When you use `pop()`, you remove the top item so that the next can be accessed. `push()` is used to put a value on the top and `peek()` is used to check the top item without popping it.

If I have the following stack

```
Sam
Dan
Adam
```

Using `pop()`, will return "Sam" and remove it from the stack, so it will look like this.

```
Dan
Adam
```

Pushing "Charlie" will make the stack look this this.

```
Charlie
Dan
Adam
```

I would have to pop twice in order to access "Adam"

Answer (score 0):

`viz` is a Stack, not an array. You can't use the array notation - `viz[node]` - on it.

```
Integer node = stack.pop();
```

this is also an error, since your `Stack` is not generic, so you must cast the result of `pop()` to `Integer` :

```
Integer node = (Integer) stack.pop();
```

An alternative would be to change the type of stack :

```
Stack<Integer> stack = new Stack<Integer>();
```

Answer (score 0):

**First**

> Type mismatch: cannot convert from Object to Integer

`stack.pop()` returns an `Object` reference, you need to type cast it to `Integer`

```
// Type caste or define stack as Stack<Integer>
Integer node = (Integer) stack.pop();
```

**Second**

> The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to Stack

```
viz[node]=1; // viz is Stack, define it as array
```